# "I am, You're only off by a year."

Tags: meaning-in-context

I said:

> and all this while I was under an impression that you must
>   around 35 years old.

He replied:

> I am. You're only off by a year.

Did he mean that he is 34 years old or 36 years old?

***What does "off by a year" mean?***

Comment: It could mean either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathmatically speaking: Let x = the estimate in years, and let y = the actual value. "Off by a year" means |x-y| = 1.

It might be worth noting that this can be extended to other units of time, and not just age. For example:

> *Our initial estimate was only off by a month*

means that the project was either completed one month early, or one month late.

> *Our baby's due date was only off by two days*

means that, if our baby's due date was May 14, the baby was born either on May 12 or May 16.

It can be imprecise, too:

> *I thought the painting would sell for $50,000 at the auction, but I was way off*.

From the information given, there's no way to tell what the painting sold for, but I can tell you it wasn't anywhere around $50,000. It could have been as low as $20,000, or it could have been $100,000 or more. However:

> *I thought the painting would sell for $50,000 at the auction, and I was only a little off*.

From that, I'd assume the painting sold for somewhere between $40,000 and $60,000, give or take.

Comment: so, what's the answer? 34 years?

Comment: @MaulikV - Or 36... The answer to the O.P.'s first question is "yes," but I chose to focus on answering the O.P.'s second question.

Comment: "Off by a year" means |x-y| = 1 - which means 34, isn't it?

Comment: No, that would be (x-y) = 1. That's why I used the notation for [absolute value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value).

Comment: Oh. I see and got it. Thank you. It's a tricky question and nicely answered by you. :)

Answer (score 0):

As Damkerng said, it could mean both. The person could have more specified to avoid ambiguity though.

> [off](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=off) - At a distance in space or **time**

This means,

> I am. You're only off by a year - He could be 34 or 36.

To avoid ambiguity, the better sentence could be...

> Quite close...just a year younger/older.

Additional: *.....that you must be around 35.* - you don't need those other words.